# React-Redux How to improve code in Reducers file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently working on an upvote/downvote feature and have shown state changes of how it on my reducers. I feel like the code in 'case types.ADD_VOTE' in my reducers file could be refactored to be cleaner.

I also included the container file as well to better understand what I am trying to achieve in the app.

**Reducers**

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes.js';


/*
@giftList: List of objects
@lastGiftId: 
*/

const initialState = {
    giftList: [],
    lastGiftId: 10000,
    totalVotes: 0,
    alreadyVoted: false,
    newMessage: ''
};

const giftReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  // let giftList;
  // let setMessage;

  switch(action.type) {
    case types.ADD_GIFT:
      let stateCopy = {...state};
      stateCopy.lastMarketId += 1;
      // create the new gift object structure.
      const giftStructure = {
        // lastGiftId: stateCopy.lastGiftId,
        newMessage: stateCopy.newMessage,
        totalVotes: 0
      };
    
      return {
        ...state,
        lastMarketId: stateCopy.lastMarketId,
        giftList: [...state.giftList, giftStructure],
        newMessage: ''
      }


    case types.SET_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state, 
        newMessage: action.payload,
      }

    case types.ADD_VOTE:
      
      let stateCopy2 = {...state};
      console.log("Already Voted Before: ", stateCopy2.alreadyVoted);
      if(stateCopy2.alreadyVoted) {
        stateCopy2.totalVotes -= 1;
        stateCopy2.alreadyVoted = false;
      } else {
        stateCopy2.totalVotes += 1;
        stateCopy2.alreadyVoted = true;
      }
      console.log("Already Voted after: ", stateCopy2.alreadyVoted);

      return {
        ...state, 
        totalVotes: stateCopy2.totalVotes, 
        alreadyVoted: stateCopy2.alreadyVoted
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default giftReducer;
```

**List Container**

```
const mapDispatchToProps =  dispatch => ({
    updateGiftMessage: (e) => { 
        console.log(e.target.value);
        dispatch(actions.setMessage(e.target.value));
    },
    addGift: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("actions: ", actions.addGift);
        dispatch(actions.addGift());
    },
    addVote: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log("event: ", e.target.getAttribute('mktid'));
        dispatch(actions.addVote(e.target.getAttribute('gift-id')));
    }
    // }
});

class ListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="All-Lists">
                <h1>LIST CONTAINER!</h1>
                    <AllGiftsDisplay giftList = {this.props.giftList} addGift={this.props.addGift} setNewMessage={this.props.setNewMessage} totalVotes = {this.props.totalVotes} lastGiftId = {this.props.lastGiftId} addVote = {this.props.addVote} lastGiftId = {this.props.lastGiftId}/>
                    <GiftCreator setNewMessage={this.props.setNewMessage} updateGiftMessage={this.props.updateGiftMessage} addGift={this.props.addGift}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListContainer);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to log any intermediate state, or pre/post state:

```
case types.ADD_VOTE:
  return {
    ...state, 
    totalVotes: state.totalVotes + (state.alreadyVoted ? -1 : 1), 
    alreadyVoted: !state.alreadyVoted,
  };
```

Increment/Decrement total votes on value of already voted, and toggle the already voted value.

Using object destructuring, reduces code a little bit

```
case types.ADD_VOTE:
  const { alreadyVoted, totalVotes } = state;
  return {
    ...state, 
    totalVotes: totalVotes + (alreadyVoted ? -1 : 1), 
    alreadyVoted: !alreadyVoted,
  };
```

Comment: I was about to answer but this is better ha, go with this. although could descontruct state to make it even cleaner ;)